# why 'list index out of range' in my django code;

Tags: python, django

IndexError: list index out of range

this is my django code :

```
import os
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "sphinx_test.settings"

#from django.core.management import setup_environ
#from sphinx_test import settings

#setup_environ(settings)


from django.db import models
from djangosphinx.models import SphinxSearch,SphinxQuerySet




class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200) 

    objects = models.Manager()
    search  = SphinxQuerySet(index="test1")


import datetime



class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Document(models.Model):
    group       = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_added  = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    content     = models.TextField()

    search      = SphinxQuerySet(File,index="test1")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'documents'
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\sphinx_test\models.py", line 16, in <module>
    class File(models.Model):
  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 52, in __new__
    kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set [`Meta.app_label`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label) to something usable.

Comment: how to set it ??like this :
class Meta:
        app_label = sphinx_test

Comment: hi ,it's ok ,and when i run my code ,it print nothing ,i want to know what happen on my databse (it's name is 'test')

Comment: coz,i found the 'test' databse don't create any table

Comment: ... Your code doesn't contain any calls to create any tables, so I'm not really surprised that nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

That's odd, that part of the code is just supposed to determine your app name. See the section [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/base.py) starting line 45. What's your app name for this?

You may be able to avoid the error by setting app_label to the name of your app in the Meta section of your model.

Comment: There is no app; it's a standalone script.

Comment: Thanks... that explains why Django can't find the app name I guess!