# link django with modules of other applications

Tags: python, django, apache

I would like to link django with an existing python application, reusing the modules, the classes and some configurationfiles that were defined in this application. All modules reside in the ./bin directory of this application. In fact the application is a forecasting system, and django will be used as the frontend to visualise the results.

The current directory structure looks like this.

```
./application/bin/module1.py
                 /module2.py
             /config.txt
             /datadir/...
             /webresults/run1/myfig.png
                        /run2/myfig.png
                        /...

./django/manage.py
        /project1/urls.py
                 /settings.py
                 /wsgi.py
        /app1/views.py
             /models.py
             /forms.py
             /...
        /templates/base.html
                  /showResults.html
                  /...
```

An apacheserver is set up to serve static pages and images from the directory ./application/webresults/ and django pages from /django/project1/wsgi.py.

For the moment I have copied all relevant modules from /application/bin/ to django/app1/ so I can reuse them eg. in views.py and models.py. With respect to maintenance of the system not an optimal solution.

So I am looking for a more elegant solution to solve this. Some of the things we would like to achieve:

- moving around the backendapplication is harder than moving around django instance, so preferable django is relocated (it was not coded in the most efficient way :-))
- reuse classes of application in django
- reuse models of django in the application
- reuse SQL_objectmapping in the application
- use one configfile for settings relevant to both django and the application

The solution we are thinking of, would be to merge all djangocode into /application/bin/ and remap the djangopath in apacheconfiguration

```
./application/bin/manage.py
                 /module1.py
                 /module2.py
                 /project1/urls.py
                          /settings.py
                          /wsgi.py
                 /app1/views.py
                      /models.py
                      /forms.py
                      /...
                 /templates/base.html
                           /showResults.html
                           /...
```

Are there any recipes on how this could be handled? Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my original question was not very clear. Since then I stumbled upon some other answers and pages that helped me , mainly on how to reuse django functionality in external modules and applications.

- http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/
- [why 'list index out of range' in my django code;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211705/why-list-index-out-of-range-in-my-django-code)
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label

With this information I managed to access my models (in apps-subfolder) from the pythonscripts on the root of the application (eg. module1.py).

In short the code to access app1.models.Mymodel from module1.py looks now like this :

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project1.settings'
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from project1 import settings
setup_environ(settings)
import app1.models

class MyChildmodel(app1.models.Mymodel):
     class Meta:
          app_label = 'app1'

     def myfunction():
          ....
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with tossing your Django project within another module. So long as your PYTHONPATH's are setup correctly, and your WSGI is configured right, everything should work normally.

My only comment would be that, tautologically, "separate things should be separate."

When I have similar problems, I usually create a simple UNIX socket server (using Tornado), that Django can communicate with for API calls, etc.

If I need to expose the functionality of the socket server, I'll throw in a cheap WSGI server (again, with Tornado) that serves up requests, and stick it under a different subdomain within my hosting configuration.

Comment: Thanks Jack. My question was really at a more basic level: on file and directory management (althought I see the advantages of the socket server). I got stuck with relative paths, abs paths, abs and relative URL's, of working directories, file locations, imports of modules, all between django modules and application modules. I agree on the tautology, although in this case one could argue that both backend and frontend are part of the same application (in my case trying to stick a django frontend to an existing backend). They also work both on the same database. My reason to put them together.